# Mixing (closed loop) stepper drivers on MKS main board

Tags: stepper-driver, mks, bigtreetech, closed-loop

Can I mix BIGTREETECH S42B closed loop stepper drivers on the MKS Gen L controller board with other drivers?

Are the pins in the same position? Would mixing work?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that should work. You need to define the correctly used drivers in your configuration. For the closed loop drivers, the board (via a break out board) has to provide the pulses to the motor driver (on the back of the stepper). If you use such a closed loop driver you need to disable the stepper driver type in your `Configuration.h` file for those you plan to insert a closed loop driver. The firmware will assume the A4988 driver is being used:

[image]

Now you need to set high enough values for the `MAXIMUM_STEPPER_RATE` (150000):

[image]

and the `MINIMUM_STEPPER_PULSE` (3):

[image]

in `Marlin/src/inc/Conditionals_adv.h` under `HAS_DRIVER(4988)`.

Comment: Hi Oscar, thank you very much! I got a gd deal on some mks tmc2208 and an skr 1.3; couldn't get a deal on closed loops :/ will report bck.